# GTKでTextViewウィジェットのテキストのスタイルを変える

Tags: c, gtk, gui

GTKでテキストウィジェットのテキストのスタイルを変えられますか？

1. 色
2. フォント
3. 書体

リファレンスなどで探したのですが最新のバージョンで使えるものがありません。

Comment: TextViewのテキスト部分です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 概要

まずは、[Text Widget Overview](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/TextWidget.html) で概要をつかむのがよさそうです。
スタイルの変更に関係が深そうな前半は、ざっと次のような内容です。

#### バッファとビュー

`GtkTextBuffer` は編集中のテキストを表現する（バッファ）。
ウィジェット `GtkTextView` は `GtkTextBuffer` を表示する（ビュー）。
バッファは任意の数のビューで表示出来る。

#### エンコーディング、文字のカウント

GTK+ におけるテキストのエンコーディングは UTF-8。
つまり、1文字が2バイト以上になり得る。
何文字目か、のカウントはオフセット（offsets）と呼ばれる。
何バイト目か、のカウントはインデックス（indexes）と呼ばれる。

#### タグ

バッファ内のテキストはタグ（tag）でマーク（mark）する事が出来る。
タグとはテキストのある範囲に付与する属性。
例えば、あるタグを "bold" と名付け、そのタグ内のテキストを太字にする、といった事が出来る。 
ただし、タグはテキストの外観に影響を与えるためだけにあるのではない。
マウスやキーボードでの操作への影響、テキストの一定範囲を編集不可にする、など様々な用途に使用される。
タグは `GtkTextTag` オブジェクトで表現される。
一つの `GtkTextTag` を、任意の数のバッファ内の任意の数のテキスト範囲に付与出来る。

各タグは `GtkTextTagTable` （タグテーブル）に格納される。
タグテーブルは一緒に使用できるタグの集合を定義する。
各バッファには、一つのタグテーブルが関連付けられ、そのタグテーブルのタグのみがそのバッファで使用出来る。
ただし、タグテーブルは複数のバッファ間で共有出来る。

タグには名前を付けてもよい。
これは例えば、"bold" と名付けたタグでテキストを太字にする、などの利便性のため。
名前を付けない、匿名のタグもある。
これは、その場（on-the-fly）でタグを作るのに便利。

#### 操作

ほとんどのテキスト操作は `GtkTextIter` で表現されるイテレータを使用して成される。
イテレータはテキストバッファ内の2文字間の位置を表現する。

---

その他、マークなどの説明が続きます。

### 公式のリファレンス、デモ

Gtk3 のリファレンスは [developer.gnome.org にあります](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/index.html)。
また、`gtk3-demo` というデモアプリケーションがあり、 これは Ubuntu であれば、`gtk-3-examples` というパッケージに含まれていますが、以下のようにソースコードも閲覧出来るようになっています。

[image: gtk3-demo screen shot]

### 簡単な例

Python ですが、一応タグを使う例です。

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import gi
gi.require_version('GLib', '2.0')
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import GLib
from gi.repository import Gtk

# イベントループ
loop = GLib.MainLoop()

# メインウィンドウ
win = Gtk.Window.new(Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL)
win.set_title("TextView のテスト")
win.connect("delete-event", lambda *x: loop.quit())

# バッファ
buf = Gtk.TextBuffer.new(None)
buf.set_text("今日は、世界！\n")

# 文字を大きくするタグ
big_tag = buf.create_tag(
    "big",
    background="#fff",
    foreground="#000",
    family="Serif",
    scale=2)

# バッファの0~2文字目（オフセット）にタグを設定
buf.apply_tag(big_tag, buf.get_iter_at_offset(0), buf.get_iter_at_offset(3))

# バッファにテキストを追加
buf.insert(buf.get_end_iter(), "Hello, ")

# バッファにテキストをタグを指定して追加
buf.insert_with_tags(buf.get_end_iter(), "world!\n", big_tag)

# ビュー
view = Gtk.TextView.new_with_buffer(buf)
view.set_editable(False)
view.set_cursor_visible(False)
win.add(view)

# スタート
win.show_all()
loop.run()
```

[image: 例の実行結果]

Comment: 回答有り難うございます。<br/>解決しました。<br/>textviewの背景（textvuew全体の）を変える方法はありますか。

Comment: @Nisuoozi  ウィジェット全体のスタイルに関しては、別の Q&A として成立しそうですので、新しい質問として投稿して下さい。